# I have a Cross object checkbox formula that checks whether a texbox has been checked or not. Why does it return a "No" if the box is checked?

Tags: formula, object, cross-object

IF(Member__r.Member__r.Confirmed_Certification_Holder__c = TRUE, "Yes", "No")

Comment: Apologies, this is to check if a CHECKBOX, not textbox, has been checked. Continues to show up False.

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Rather than add that correction as a comment, you can edit your question to change it. You will find "Share Edit Follow Flag" at the bottom left of every post; just click "Edit" on your question, make your corrections and save. You can edit your own posts without approval or review, even with not much reputation.

Answer (score 0):

this needs modify like below. checkbox will allow true or false.

```
IF(Member__r.Member__r.Confirmed_Certification_Holder__c = TRUE, True, False)
```

Comment: the value still returns false even if the field is true.

Comment: Are you referencing two objects or single object?

Comment: If its single object reference then you need to use IF(Member__r.Confirmed_Certification_Holder__c = TRUE, True, False)

Comment: The member object is referenced in a formula in another object labeled Volunteer

Comment: @AnkaiahBandi The formula is redundant. One can always say just `IF(Member__r.Confirmed_Certification_Holder__c, 'Yes','No')`. A checkbox is already a Boolean value.

Comment: I want to be able to pull the checkbox value from the Member object to confirm it has been checked or not and have that information on the volunteer object.

Comment: The problem I'm having is that with either formula, the value is coming back false, even when it should be true.

Comment: what is the formula return type in volunteer object?

Comment: @sfdcfox, Got it!! thanks for the update. If the formula return type as text then use the formula condition suggested by sfdcfox. If the formula return type as check box then use Member__r.Confirmed_Certification_Holder__c